# Not able to get my setup 404 status code, instead getting 500 status code for incorrect id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to Nodejs and I am trying to play with the stuffs using using node js.

I created one api (using Nodejs, Express,Mongoose) to read users in which I am trying to search an Invalid user id(id is not matching with any records in the mongoDB).

The 404 response never triggers.I enter an incorrect ID and get 500.

Attaching the code screenshot for reference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLSAc.png)

Comment: Code in questions on stackoverflow needs to pasted in as text, NOT as images.  Please use the edit link below your question to fix this.  This is for a whole bunch of reasons like so it can be searched, so it is accessible and so that people who want to write answers can copy/paste/modify the code into answers without retyping from scratch.  Please fix your question.

Answer (score 2):

for using findById you should pass only the id as a single value not in an object. so update your code as

```
User.findById(_id)
```

and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/useres/:id'), async (req, res) => {

    const _id = req.params.id;
    let user = await User.findById(_id).then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
            res.status(404).send()
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(user)
        }
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send()
    })
}
```